# How to replicate JCryption1.1.js encryption method in python or java

Tags: javascript, python, encryption

I need to authenticate to a server without using a browser, instead i want to create a python script that does the job for me. This server uses  JCryption 1.1.js that supposedly uses the  plaintext RSA encryption (RSA/ECB/null padding)

```
$.jCryption.encrypt = function (string, keyPair, callback) {
        var charSum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
            charSum += string.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var tag = '0123456789abcdef';
        var hex = '';
        hex += tag.charAt((charSum & 0xF0) >> 4) + tag.charAt(charSum & 0x0F);

        var taggedString = hex + string;

        var encrypt = [];
        var j = 0;

        while (j < taggedString.length) {
            encrypt[j] = taggedString.charCodeAt(j);
            j++;
        }

        while (encrypt.length % keyPair.chunkSize !== 0) {
            encrypt[j++] = 0;
        }

        function encryption(encryptObject) {
            var charCounter = 0;
            var j, block;
            var encrypted = "";

            function encryptChar() {
                block = new BigInt();
                j = 0;
                for (var k = charCounter; k < charCounter + keyPair.chunkSize; ++j) {
                    block.digits[j] = encryptObject[k++];
                    block.digits[j] += encryptObject[k++] << 8;
                }
                var crypt = keyPair.barrett.powMod(block, keyPair.e);
                var text = keyPair.radix == 16 ? biToHex(crypt) : biToString(crypt, keyPair.radix);
                encrypted += text + " ";
                charCounter += keyPair.chunkSize;
                if (charCounter < encryptObject.length) {
                    setTimeout(encryptChar, 1)
                } else {
                    var encryptedString = encrypted.substring(0, encrypted.length - 1);
                    if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
                        callback(encryptedString);
                    } else {
                        return encryptedString;
                    }

                }
            }

            setTimeout(encryptChar, 1);
        }

        encryption(encrypt);
    };
```

The server sends me the modulus (n) , the exponent (e) and maxdigits.
This is an example:

> {"e":"10001","n":"f74ae94f55cc2dcfa92d4f82d1f4816e99b4082d4d459aed0dda228273eceb305021c17ac3d49e76cdc5c0e49038a361c8e465326e5fb6c418ddbf28a407dfd7","maxdigits":"67"}

With the keypair above, if i submit the password "test" i get this encrypted string :

> "5912c99d8fd7bd26b7e99a1bb80e5b20f540527db7fe4c1e45548226efab376bdf232b975bab346845dcdbf1578387bc03f17261b5947ccc4cf2407c2baa42b0"

I tried encrypting myself the password and username using pyCrypto , i didn't get the same encrypted string.

Does anyone have a solution?